# Using NODE_PATH in electron to map folders inside src/ as modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to set `NODE_PATH` on my electron project to `NODE_PATH=src` but it is not working.

The idea is to be able to require any folder inside `src` by it's name.

So in the case of the folder structure

```
src/
--main.js
--components/
----index.js
```

from `main.js` I should be able to use

`import components from "components"`

instead of

`import components from "./components"`

---

I've already tried setting it in `start script`:

`"start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src electron-forge start"`

as well as in a `.env` file to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing here what has worked for me:-

At the entry point of your application add this line:

```
global.require.main.paths.push('./src');
```

The above is equivalent to to setting the NODE_PATH variable. Make sure this line is added before any of your code is executed.